# Using the latest versions of aapt and adb in 32-bit OS

Tags: android, linux, adb, aapt

I use debian 32-bit and I installed Eclipse and the latest Android SDK.
However, when I try to use it - it shows this error message:

```
/opt/eclipse-android/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt : Syntax error : Unterminated quoted string"
```

and it also displays messages about the lack of `adb`

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: latest versions of Android SDK packages are 64bit. check with `file aapt`

Comment: `adb` comes with `platform-tools` package

Comment: Did this error come up during install?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either use 64-bit OS or downgrade your Android SDK to [build-tools_r23.0.3](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.3-linux.zip) and [platform-tools_r23.0.1](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip)

Answer (score 0):

It’s just related to build-tools .Google dropped support for 32 bit processors starting with this version so either you need to use a 64 bit operating system but you need to make sure you have a machine with a 64 bit processor or use version 23 of build tools ,[you can download it here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.3-linux.zip) and you need to change also the [platform tools](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip) ,just copy them and replace the existing  ones in Android SDK home directory  .Here is the [reference](https://www.techiediaries.com/mobiledev/build-tools24-0-2aapt-syntax-error-unterminated-quoted-string/)